java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in OpenAPI Generator: Jackson YAMLFactory _createContentReference Method Not Found
I'm working with OpenAPI Generator in a Java project and trying to generate a client from a YAML specification file. However, I'm consistently encountering the following error during the build process:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:441)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3413)

My Environment:
OpenAPI Generator Plugin Version: 6.0.0
Jackson DataFormat YAML Version: Tried both 2.14.2 and 2.17.1
Java Version: 17
Spring Boot Version: 3.x
Relevant build.gradle Snippet:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '6.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/api-client"

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2'
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2'
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.2'
        force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.14.2'
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set('java')
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/src/main/resources/api-spec.yaml")
    invokerPackage.set('com.example.client')
    modelPackage.set('com.example.client.model')
    apiPackage.set('com.example.client.api')
}

What I’ve Tried:
  - Forcing different Jackson YAML versions (2.14.2, 2.15.0, 2.17.1),
          but the error persists. 

     - Clearing the .gradle cache to ensure dependency    resolution isn’t
          affected by cached artifacts.
     -  Verifying that all Jackson dependencies are aligned in the same
          version (2.14.2) to avoid compatibility issues.

Question:
What could be causing this NoSuchMethodError with the _createContentReference method in YAMLFactory, and how can I resolve it? Is there a specific Jackson version that aligns with OpenAPI Generator 6.0.0 and Java 17?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
